# How to change the title of the button in the user profile form in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, forms, users

How do I change the name of the button in the user_profile_form in Drupal 7?
I alter the user profile using `hook_form_alter()`.

```
function userform_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form' ) { 
    // I define a submit button like:
    $form['submit'] = array( 
      '#type' => 'submit', 
      '#value' => t('Continue'), 
    );

    //Then I can change it with this code:  
    // Change 'Continue' to 'Sign in'. 
    $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Sign in');
  }
}
```

It works for all elements (buttons) I define myself, but it doesn't work for the default button in the user profile form.
This the rendered HTML for the "Save" button:

```
<input id="edit-submit" class="form-submit" type="submit" value="Save" name="op">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [profile_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--profile--profile.module/function/profile_form_alter/7)